# Unable to update to Xcode 9 from app store - this item is temporarily unavailable

Tags: ios, app-store, macos-sierra, ios11, xcode9

Unable to update  Xcode 9 from app store,

am getting "this item is temporarily unavailable"

[image]

this is my MAC version
[image]

Answer (score 3):

"App Store" -> "Store" -> "Check for Unfinished Downloads"

Comment: Please I have Xcode 8.3.3 and still now I didn't receive the update notification for the Xcode 9 in the app store. Is that normal?

Comment: By doing this, the App Store prompted me to switch to the U.S. Store - don't know why it was elsewhere - and then I was able to update xcode and finally it started downloading. So +1 this

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are in the right App Store. I changed countries and so it was not allowing me to download it as it was still thinking I was in my country where I came from. Once I switched the store I was able to download it.